# How to Display mysql table data in a wordpress page?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

My aim is to develop a standard website using wordpress. I need to display data from a table in mysql database on my wordpress  page.I have created a table in the same database that wordpress was installed.(DBname-digitigers,table_name:BookDetails: 13 columns).
Please help me.

Comment: try this  Link: https://deliciousbrains.com/managing-custom-tables-wordpress/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   <?php
    global $wpdb;
      $results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM table_name order by id DESC"  );
foreach($results as $res) { 

        //echo $res->col1;

     }
    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks @Sajid  for reply can you give me example to display records in tabular form.

Comment: I hope now you can understand. if any problem knock me:)

Comment: A big Thanks to @Sajid  it's working.

Comment: I have less than 15 reputation I Given upvote It's not showing.